# Disable software renderer jpct-ae

Tags: android, jpct

I use of JPCT-AE for Android,I need disable software renderer and enable opengl renderer from FrameBuffer.
I found this code for JPCT desktop but I don't know how can I change that for Jpct-AE.
JPCT desktop Code:

```
buffer.disableRenderer(IRenderer.RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
buffer.enableRenderer(IRenderer.RENDERER_OPENGL);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for this. jPCT-AE has no software renderer, so nothing has to be disabled.